# INSERT not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple INSERT that is not working. Can you php/mySQL experts do a quick scan. When I process the code, it does say "successful" i.e. "1 record added'" and "successfully created directory" - but there is NO new directory I see on the server AND it adds a record in the db but all the fields are empty?

```
include("_inc/config.php"); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (id, active, namefirst, namelast, email, username, password, birthyear, gender, country, postalcode, education, dimension, referredby, pic_profile, pic_background, origination, customerid) VALUES ('','$_POST[active]','$_POST[namefirst]','$_POST[namelast]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[birthyear]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[postalcode]','$_POST[education]','$_POST[dimension]','$_POST[referredby]','$_POST[pic_profile]','$_POST[pic_background]','$_POST[origination]','$_POST[customerid]')";

$newdir=$_POST['username'];

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 record added";
echo "<br><br>";

// Build Directories
mkdir("../".$newdir,0777); 
chmod("../".$newdir,0777);
mkdir("../".$newdir."/assets/",0777); 
chmod("../".$newdir."/assets/",0777);

if("../".mkdir($newdir, 0777, true))
{
    echo 'successfully created directory';
} 
else 
{
    die('problem creating directory'); 
} 

mysql_close($con)
```

FORM

```
<form role="form" name="form" action="mpx_signup_process.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nameandemail">Name and Email</label>
                                    <input name="namefirst" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="namelast" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><hr></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="accountinfo">Account Information</label>
                                    <input name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="User Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password Repeat">
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="personalinfo">Personal Information</label>
                                 <h3>Country</h3>
                                <select name="country" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="USA">United States</option>
                                    <option value="UMI">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                                    <option value="USA">- - - - - -</option>
                                    <option value="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
                                    <option value="ALB">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="ASM">American Samoa</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="referredby">Postal Code</label>
                                    <input name="postalcode" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPostalCode" placeholder="Postal Code">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                                <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios4" value="01">
                                    Male
                                </label>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <label>
                                     <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios5" value="02">
                                     Female
                                </label>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios6" value="03">
                                    Other
                                </label>
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>
                                <select name="birthyear" class="form-control">
                                <?php 
                                   for($i = 2010 ; $i > 1920; $i--){
                                      echo "<option value=".$i.">$i</option>";
                                   }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="education">Education</label>
                                <select name="education" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="01">Pre High School</option>
                                    <option value="02">High School</option>
                                    <option value="03">Some College</option>
                                    <option value="04">College Graduate</option>
                                    <option value="05">Graduate Degree</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="referredby">Referred By</label>
                                    <input name="referredby" class="form-control" id="exampleInputreferredby" placeholder="Referred By">
                                </div>


                                <input type="hidden" name="active" value="no">
                                <input type="hidden" name="dimension" value="00">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pic_profile" value="mpx_profilepic.jpg">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pic_background" value="mpx_bsckgroundpic.jpg">
                                <?php
                                    $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');                
                                ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="origination" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>
```

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated as it is not secure. Please switch to PDO or MySQLi

Comment: can you show me a replacement sample while I Google your advice

Comment: Other then being deprecated, you're wide open to SQL Injections.

Comment: Is it `$sql,$con` or `$con,$sql`? Or does it work in both ways?

Comment: Can you point me to an article or reference example online - I am looking at php.net right now for samples...

Comment: Please show us the form?

Comment: you aren't enclosing the string properly in $sql (insert statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form, add a `method="POST"`

```
<form role="form" name="form" method="POST" action="mpx_signup_process.php">
```

Because `$_POST["username"]` is empty the new directory name is empty thus the reason for not creating it I assume.

I would also suggest adding a check to determine if the record was infact inserted. The code above will ALWAYS return `"1 record added"` which is incorrect. Use something similar to [mysql_rows_affected](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) but using mysqli or PDO rather.

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
  echo "1 record added";
  echo "<br><br>";

  // Build Directories
  mkdir("../".$newdir,0777); 
  chmod("../".$newdir,0777);
  mkdir("../".$newdir."/assets/",0777); 
  chmod("../".$newdir."/assets/",0777);

}
else
{
  echo "No records added";
}
```

Comment: That fixed it!!!!! BUT having said that, do you advise I go back and rework based on earlier security comments?? i.e. PDO

Comment: Absolutely. But first understand the logic that more important then upgrade to mysqli_(easiest - almost the same as mysql_) or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Sure it will always "successfully created directory"!

Please look,

```
if("../".mkdir($newdir, 0777, true))
```

When `mkdir` eval to `false` (fail), you'll get

```
if("../" . false)
// or
if("../false") // maybe
// or just
if("../")      // maybe, I'm unsure.
```

and it's non empty string, BTW, it always eval to `true` ensuring you hit the

```
echo 'successfully created directory';
```

Answer (score 0):

In `$sql` you're not escaping the string properly

the php post variables in `$sql` are as `$_POST[namelast]`, `$_POST[email]`, etc, whereas it should be `$_POST['namelast']`, `$_POST['email']`, etc.